# About AFNetworking Localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, afnetworking

I am now doing the AFNetworking localization. I have created a strings file named AFNetworking.strings, its content is like this

```
"Request failed: %@ (%ld)"     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  %@ (%ld)";
```

The static part works well, it can translated into other language when the system language is changed. But the dynamic part ( %@ ) is still English.

So I look through the source code of AFNetworking.

```
   [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Request failed: %@ (%ld)", @"AFNetworking", nil), [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:response.statusCode], (long)response.statusCode]
```

AFNetworking use the **localizedStringForStatusCode** method to get a localized status string.

So I print the return string of this method. I found that whatever the system language is, the string is always English.

Do you guys have good solution of this problem?

Thanks a lot!